# How to fix accuracy error?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, functional-style

When I run the code this type of error appears:

```
General::munfl: 6.1377*10^169/(31077497979558314002936012676501890479759793586974542804756910050522836128971062<<164>>000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
```

How can this be corrected?

```
f[a_, n_] = 
  Integrate[r^n*Exp[-a*r], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, n > 0}];

coeff[n_] := 2*Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!]/n^2;

Px3[n1_, n2_, \[Epsilon]0_] := 
  Px3[n1, n2, \[Epsilon]0] = 
   If[n1 > n2, Px3[n2, n1, \[Epsilon]0], 
    coeff[n1]*coeff[n2]*(-0.85)*
     Total[Map[
       Function[{x}, f[1.3 + 1/n1 + 1/n2, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]]], 
       CoefficientRules[
        Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n1, 2, 2*r/n1]*
         Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n2, 2, 2*r/n2], r]]]];

Table[N[Px3[n1, n2, 30]], {n1, 1, 80}, {n2, 1, 80}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use machine precision

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, n_] = 
  Integrate[r^n*Exp[-a*r], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, n > 0}];

coeff[n_] := 2*Sqrt[n!/(-1 + n)!]/n^2;

Px3[n1_, n2_, ϵ0_] := 
  Px3[n1, n2, ϵ0] = 
   If[n1 > n2, Px3[n2, n1, ϵ0], 
    coeff[n1]*coeff[n2]*(-17/20)*
     Total[Map[Function[{x}, f[13/10 + 1/n1 + 1/n2, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]]], 
       CoefficientRules[
        Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n1, 2, 2*r/n1]*
         Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n2, 2, 2*r/n2], r]]]];

table = Table[N[Px3[n1, n2, 30]], {n1, 1, 80}, {n2, 1, 80}];

ListContourPlot[table, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]